# Closing a nested async generator prematurely

Tags: python, generator, python-3.7, python-asyncio, python-3.8

I'm looking how to close a nested async generator without fully iterating it. For example:

```py
import asyncio


async def gen1():
    yield 1
    yield 2


async def gen2():
    async for nr in gen1():
        yield nr


async def main():
    stream = gen2()
    print(await stream.__anext__())  # 1
    await stream.aclose()


asyncio.run(main())
```

However, this results in a `RuntimeError`:

```
unhandled exception during asyncio.run() shutdown
task: <Task finished name='Task-2' coro=<<async_generator_athrow without __name__>()> exception=RuntimeError("can't send non-None value to a just-started coroutine")>
RuntimeError: can't send non-None value to a just-started coroutine
```

Comment: This still happens if you remove the `await stream.aclose()`. In my tests, it seems to happen whenever `main` calls another function that then leaves an async generator half-iterated, but not when `main` directly creates an async generator and leaves it half-iterated.

Comment: @user2357112 Noticed that as well. I included the `stream.aclose` since, to my knowledge, this is the correct way of exiting a generator (by raising a `GeneratorExit` through the call) if we are traversing the generator manually (without `async for`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original issue was present when testing with Python versions `3.7.4` and `3.8.0b4`. It has since been fixed in `3.8.0rc1`:

https://bugs.python.org/issue38013